# Pop up alert box

Tags: flutter

I have a piece of code of login connected to the firebase database, but when a user has wrongly entered email or password i want to have a pop up alert box be displayed as now it is only being displayed in the screen before the register button in red. The code is posted below. Please can you help me.

Thank you.

```
class Register extends StatefulWidget {

 final Function toggleView;

 Register({this.toggleView});

 @override
 _RegisterState createState() => _RegisterState();
}

class _RegisterState extends State<Register> {

 final AuthService _auth = AuthService();
 final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
 bool loading = false;

 // text field state
 String email = '';
 String password = '';
 String error = "";

 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   return loading ? Loading() : Scaffold(
     backgroundColor: Colors.brown[100],
     appBar: AppBar(
       backgroundColor: Colors.brown[400],
       elevation: 0.0,
       title: Text('Sign Up'),
       actions: <Widget>[
         FlatButton.icon(
           icon: Icon(Icons.person),
           label: Text('Login'),
           onPressed: () {
             widget.toggleView();
           },
         )
       ],
     ),
     body: Container(
       padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 20.0, horizontal: 50.0),
       child: Form(
         key: _formKey,
         child: Column(
           children: <Widget>[
             SizedBox(height: 20.0),
             TextFormField(
               decoration: textInputDecoration.copyWith(hintText: 'Email'),
               validator: (val) => val.isEmpty ? 'Enter an email' : null,
               onChanged: (val) {
                 setState(() => email = val);
               }
             ),
             SizedBox(height: 20.0),
             TextFormField(
               decoration: textInputDecoration.copyWith(hintText: 'Password'),
               obscureText: true,
               validator: (val) => val.length < 6 ? 'Enter a password of more than 6 characters' : null,
               onChanged: (val) {
                 setState(() => password = val);
               },
             ),
             SizedBox(height: 20.0),
             RaisedButton(
               color: Colors.pink[400],
               child: Text(
                 'Register',
                 style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
               ),
               onPressed: () async {
                 if (_formKey.currentState.validate())
                 {
                   setState(() => loading = true);
                   dynamic result = await _auth.registerWithEmailAndPassword(email, password);
                   if (result == null)
                   {
                     setState(() {
                       error = 'Please enter a vaild email';
                     loading = false;
                     });
                   }
                 }
               },
             ),
             SizedBox(height: 20.0),
             Text(
               error,
               style: TextStyle(color: Colors.red, fontSize: 14.0),
             )
           ],
         ),
        ),
     ),
   );
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pretty much easy

```
 showDialog(
        context: context,
        builder: (BuildContext context) {
          return CupertinoAlertDialog(
            title: Text("AppName"),
            content: Text("Are you sure you want to delete this?"),
            actions: <Widget>[
              FlatButton(
                child: Text("Yes"), 
                onPressed: () {
                  //whatever actions you want to perform 
                },
              ),
              FlatButton(
                child: Text("No"),
                onPressed: () {
                  Navigator.of(context).pop();
                },
              )
            ],
          );
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

You should show a dialog during a call to setState

```
if (result == null)
{
 showDialog(
  context: context,
   builder: (BuildContext context){
    return AlertDialog(
     title: Text("Please enter a vaild email"),
     content: Text("Description if need"),
    );
   }
 );
 setState(() {
  loading = false;
 });
}
```

and remove

```
Text(
   error,
   style: TextStyle(color: Colors.red, fontSize: 14.0),
 )
```

Comment: Can you please help me for the password field also?